# Help making extruded vent on a circle flat surface

Tags: modeling

I've been racking my brain trying to figure out how to do these air vent folds that actually look like their coming out of the flat surface (pic 1).  Any ideas on how to achieve this given my current geometry? (pic 2)

Many thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unrelated, but [please](https://imgur.com/a/LDw8TkR), my eyes are hurting.

Comment: haha i saw that but couldn't be bothered to fix it just yet